# How to pass parameter in $_POST[]?

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a file named main.php, where there is a form and the action of the form is another php file which is brand.php.That means,upon submission of the form in the main.php file the brand.php file will be fired as action.

The form portion of main.php file is here:-

```
 <form action="brand.php" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" value="Brand Name" id="b1" name="brand_button">
 </form>
```

Now the form portion of brand.php file is here:-

```
echo "<form action='size.php' method='POST'>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{


    echo "<input type='submit' name=".$row["brand"]." value=" .   $row["brand"] . " style='height:20px;width:100px'>";

    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    $count=$count+1;
}
echo "</form>";
```

Now the actual problem is upon submission each time in the loop of the brand.php file I need to fire another php file which is size.php .

The code of size.php file is here:-

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die("Abhra...unable");
if($db->connect_error)
{
     echo "Unable to connect"; 
}

$bname=$_POST[];

echo '<br>';
$q1= "select DISTINCT size from garments where brand='.$bname.'";
$result=$db->query($q1);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{

     $count=1;
     echo "<form action='size.php' method='POST'>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {


          echo "<input type='submit' name=.$count. value=" . $row["size"] . " style='height:20px;width:100px'>";

       echo '<br>';
       echo '<br>';
       $count=$count+1;
     }
     echo "</form>";
} 

$db->close();
?>
```

Now I have doubt that in the line 7 of the size.php file,what will be the parameter of $_POST[], specially when in the calling page the corresponding name part of the button is also a query string $row["brand"].

Comment: two questions, 

why do you need to fire it for each time of the loop
why are you using on a loop for the input the same name over and over?

Comment: Actually I need to create a tree type query structure,,,,upon clicking on the brand button available brand name will be shown as buttons.Then after clicking on such buttons the available size of that particular brand will be displayed as buttons once again and so on,,,

Comment: Simply give the submit button in brand.php a fixed name – there is no need to transport the brand via the button name, since you have put it into the button value already.

Comment: By tree type you mean something like this? https://www.jstree.com/demo/

is this query affected by some kind of information from the users?

why don't you precompute the query when a change is done and auto export it to a json file? (if you can avoid going to the db it's always better)

Comment: No, no, no:  1) You need exactly *one* `<input type='submit'..>` button, 2) you'll want an `<input name="XYZ" value="ABC">` element - that's *NOT* "type=submit" - for your _POST[] variables.  Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Comment: @CBroe ,,,thank you...its working now.

Comment: @paulsm4,....ok,,,now I get it...thnx

Comment: The select statement is not working <br>$bname=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bra_but');
echo $bname;
echo '<br>';
$q1= "select DISTINCT size from garments where brand='.$bname.'";

Comment: I need to submit the $bname variable value too to the next page ,how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current way of working, there are two distinct problems:

- from the HTML page generated by `main.php` you submit the `brand_button` data, which is so available in the `brand.php` script, *but then not to the `size.php` script*!
  You might solve this by generating (in `brand.php`) something like
  `<input type="hidden" name="brand_button" value=<?php echo $_POST['brand_button']; ?> />`
- even once the above ensures you transmit the POST data to `size.php` you have to use it correctly: with `$bname=$_POST[];` you only got an array into `$bname`!
  It should be `$bname = $_POST['brand_button'];`

Comment: Can you please elaborate the technique ? I am suffering from the same problem.I need brand_button data in the size.php page too,,,but I did not get the data there.

Comment: @Abhradip Not sure to exactly understand what you mean when asking for elaborate the technique. In the code you posted, you have only to: 1) in `brand.php`, add a line `echo '<input type ="hidden" ...>';` as detailed in my first point above (for instance as 2nd line just after `echo '<form ...>';)`; 2) in size.php change the `$bname` affectation as detailed in my 2nd point above. With only that, all should work as expected. Nevertheless I may have missed something: feel free to ask if it still fails.